# "Don't ask about" on Web Apps Tour

Tags: support, status-completed, help-center, tour

From [The Tour](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour), specifically the "Don't ask about" section

[image: screen shot]

Weren't the "Creating or developing a web application" and "Web browsers, including features and browser extensions/add-ons" items moved to the top of the list? If not, they should be. (That's a majority of our off-topic questions.)

Also, the "recommendations" prohibition has changed to be recommendations requests in general. This should be re-worded to match up with the [Help Center](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). (And is should be "recommendation *requests*" that are off-topic. "Recommendations" are what those naughty questions are trying to engender.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Makes sense, I've updated the Tour and Help pages.

Comment: Haven't we dropped the bit about "prior research"?

Comment: Oh yes, indeed we have. Now sorted.